# Missing icons in Visual Studio 2015 after installing extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I followed the [steps to create a Visual Studio extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx), however after installing the extension in VS2015, Visual Studio does not display any icons in toolbars in menus. Any idea what could be the cause and how to restore icons.

Comment: I have this problem too. Just sayin'

Comment: Same for me, although I did a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2015 and doesn't show any icons in the toolbar nor anywhere else (e.g. solution explorer, server explorer, etc...)

Comment: @Maurits van Beusekom: I have a hint it is caused by hardware rendering. What video card are you using?

Comment: @AlexRoz: I have resolved my problem with the help of Microsoft Support. Turns out that in my case the environment variable %LocalAppData% did not map to a valid location on my harddisk. Fixing this issue resolved the problem I was experiencing with the icons not loading in Visual Studio 2015. Thank you however for offering your assistance.

Comment: @Maurits van Beusekom, Thank you! But in my case the %LocalAppData% is set correctly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT:  [Download the fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095681) from Microsoft.**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095681

Answer (score 19):

I had same issue and it was resolved by just remove the `ImageLibrary.cache` file from

`C:\Users\< user ame>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ImageLibrary`
and re-open the visual studio

Comment: This helped me in VS 2017 too. AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_e263f642\ImageLibrary\

Comment: Same goes for me, also worked in VS 2017. FYI - the subfolder in VisualStudio is not always the same, but go for the 15.[then some alphanumeric sequence].         
  
  And for those who can't locate their AppData\Local, just type in `%localappdata%` from File Explorer.

Comment: @SHADOW.NET,  which Visual Studio you use?

Comment: Different visual studio has different directory name. Please refer above comment of @RicardoVirtudazoJr

Comment: It's a very helpful solution. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: This was the answer for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a solution yesterday.  Here is the link.  I had to close and reopen VS for the update to take effect. Worked like a charm!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095681

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on a windows 10 upgrade and installing an extension. VS couldn't seem to find the files required under my windows profile. I realized that I was logging in through my windows Live login (my email) and not my local user account. I logged in under my local account and it now has no issues finding all files it needs. Hopefully this helps someone with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue intermittently. Updating the computer's display drivers may resolve the issue.

Comment: Updated NVidia drivers, did not help. Re-install Visual Studio, the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the issue after asking on Msdn forum I got some suggestion and got myself sorted.
Here is the link with the explaination.
[Link MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4eff982d-a1b3-4f01-a77e-9e1a9db8bfb8/icon-missing-on-toolbar-in-visual-studio-2015-vs-2015?forum=vssetup&prof=required)

Comment: Thank you, @user5177742: I run as administrator but the problem occurs when installing/uninstalling extension (VSIX)

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio 2017` solve this ;
Open this folder

> C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_533da44c\ImageLibrary

than remove the `ImageLibrary.cache` file

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015, 2017 solve this ; Open this folder

> 1. Press Windows Key + R (Open Run from).
> 2. Type "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\".
> 3. Go to "15.0_......" (Your random name) Directory.
> 4. Go to "ImageLibrary" Directory.
> 5. Remove "ImageLibrary.cache" file.
> 6. Starting VS2015 or VS2017.