# icon missing on tool bar in visual studio 2015 (VS 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have just install vs 2015, but when I open it I am not getting the icon/image on the toolbar. I have tried to reset the toolbar but that did not do the trick. I also tried to do a repair but it did not solve this problem.

I am wondering if someone experience something similar ?

For the moment, I added the text on to the button so at least I can use it, but it is far from been ideal.
I am on a corporate enviroment (no admin priviliges), one of my colleague tried and it work without problem for him.

Comment: What toolbar? Which icons are missing?

Comment: it is all toolbar and all icons. I will make a screenshoot on Tuesday. I am off for few days

Comment: I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: the same issue. Clean istalaction of windows10+VS2015. Icons disappears after I installed Windows Universal Platfrom tooling by chosing File->Project->Windows Universal. Visual Studio then asked me to install the tooling and after restarts icons were gone. I dont have any other extensions installed, only the default instalation without any custom settings

Comment: In previous setup Win8+VS2015 icons also disappeared after I installed any extension, e.g Productivity Power Tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing icons in Visual Studio 2015 after installing extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711201/missing-icons-in-visual-studio-2015-after-installing-extension)

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem after an upgarde to Windows 10 where all my icons had disappeared. Also had a problem with a cordova android build getting stuck at "run.bat --nobuild --device --debug". Think this was permission related.

I fixed my issue as follows:

Right click the Visual Stuido 2015 shortcut, and choose "run as administrator", and see if that works.

To always run as admin, right click the Visual Stuido 2015 shortcut, click advanced, and then tick "run as administrator".

Also, in my case, after upgrade to Windows 10, my user account was put into a user group called "HelpLibraryUpdaters", I switched this to "Administrator".

Comment: Run as administrator solved this problem to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to disable hardware acceleration to use software rendering: Options -> General ->Automatically Adjust client experience based on client performance. I was able to get icons back but only after several restart cycles. I have NVidia Quadro video card which might cause rendering issues.

Comment: Thanks a million AlexRoz, I will try this.

Comment: The icons disappeared again :( However I keeped playing with the settings, I restarted visual studio few times and now its working and i have the 'Automatically Adjust client experience' turned on!

Answer (score 3):

Delete the folder

> %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ImageLibrary

and let VS re-generate the image cache.

Comment: deleting the "ImageLibrary" folder and "run as administrator" solved my issue..thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Launch Visual Studio in safe mode (devenv /safemode).
Icons should appear in toolbar from now on.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is what I am getting for vs2015.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z89jo.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z89jo.jpg)

As you can see all the icon are not there, I hover over the properties icon so it is more visible.

EDIT : I did a uninstall and than reinstall, put it did not do the trick, however I suspect some preference files were kept after the uninstall as after the reinstall the same setting for vs 2015 were there.
I will dig around this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the VS2015 installed by unity3d 5.2, several icons were missing; To note, unity3d automatically installs an addon, and similar questions googled were about addons making icons disappear.
I tried the solutions /safe mode, restart etc. But the only answer that helped was the "run as administrator" solution (first answer); I ran it as admin, icons reappeared, and after that, I could also run it as user with the same effect. So after running it once as administrator, before making it always run as admin, you can just simply try to re-run it as user afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some required information missing from the registry or the image loading service is not correctly created or initialized.

Installing this update resolved the issue.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095681

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual studio has solved this problem for me